# Angular router-outlet not rendering

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-standalone-components

I'm trying to work on my first angular project using standalone components.

I have 3 basic components that are routed like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent},
  {path: 'notes', component: NotesComponent},
  {path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent}
];
```

If my app.component.html only contains `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` it renders the content of the routed component.

If my app.component.html contains the following instead the content of the router-outlet is not rendered at all. All components in this example just contain the default `<p>x works!</p>`

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';
import {NavigationComponent} from "./shared/navigation/navigation.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, RouterOutlet, NavigationComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

route configuration

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    importProvidersFrom(LucideAngularModule.pick({ CalendarDays, NotebookText, Settings })),
  ]
};

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

[screenshot of dom elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhKKJ.png)

Does anyone know why I would get this unexpected behavior?

Comment: show all the routes configuration and how routes are called

Comment: share your app.component.ts

Comment: i updated the inital post with the app.component.ts and the route configuration

Comment: Could you please check if it is really not there? Dom node does not exist? Maybe the navigation component is causing a side effect.

Comment: I added a screenshot to the post showing that the router-outlet is in the dom but the content component of the router-outlet is not showing

Comment: Do you have an error in browser console ?

Comment: You imported two times RouterOutlet inside AppComponent decorator. It should not be the source of your issue, but better fix that.
Why you tagged the question with angular-ui-router? That's not native angular router but a third party lib. Are you using both in your app?

Comment: Thanks, no im not using it. I just saw angular and router and assumed it was related.

Comment: does your application compile?

what do you do differently from https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-krwxkt?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts